# How should I structure a small non-fiction book/paper about a groundbreaking product/invention?

Tags: technical-writing, structure, non-fiction, planning

I want to write a book/paper about an invention I have thought and developed conceptually.
But I'm really struggling on what I should include in it and how to structure the information.

Any suggestions or examples of similar books or papers will be much appreciated.

Comment: The proper form for describing a "groundbreaking invention" is a patent application.

Comment: Kinda an example, i bookmarked this a while ago but haven't read the whole thing. might help you out. http://www.niac.usra.edu/files/studies/final_report/737Lipson.pdf

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b Very helpful, what came to my mind is the 'Hyperloop' paper and the original Bitcoin paper, which are very close/similar to what I'm asking, thanks.